# Object inside array impossible to update

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have my model in Mongoose which inside has an array of objects. Inside this array I have an object called disabledBy to which I want to set data but Mongoose always tells me that it does not receive information for said object.

This is my Model:

Purchases

...

```
    payments: [{
        createdAt: {
            type: String,
            required:true
        },
        paymentNumber: {
            type: Number,
            default:0
        },
        previousBalance:{
            type: Number,
            required: [true, 'El Saldo anterior es obligatorio'],
            default:0
        },
        paymentAmount:{
            type: Number,
            required: [true, 'La Cantidad del Pago(Abono) es obligatorio'],
            default:0
        },
        outstandingBalance:{
            type: Number,
            required: [true, 'El Saldo pendiente es obligatorio'],
            default:0
        },
        createdBy:{
            uid : { type: String, required: true },
            username:{ type: String, required: true }
        },
        comments: {
            type: String,
            maxlength:300,
        },
        status: {
            type: Boolean, 
            default: true
        },
        disabledBy:{ // this is the object i try to update
            uid:{
                type: String,
                required:true
            },
            username:{
                type: String,
                required:true
            },
            date:{
                type: Date,
                default: Date.now
            },
            comments: {
                type: String,
                maxlength:300,
                required: [true, 'El Comentario es obligatorio']
            }
        }
    }],
```

And this is my code from Express:

```
       const payment = await Purchase.updateOne( 
        { _id: id, 'payments._id': body.paymentId },
        {
          $set: {
            'payments.$.status': false,
            'payments.$.disabledBy': {
                uid: req.user._id,
                username: req.user.username,   
                comments: body.comments
            }
          }
        } ,{ new: true });
```

It should be noted that when trying to update the status property of payments, it is executed correctly but not disabledBy.

This is the error reported by Mongoose:

> error Purchase validation failed: payments.0.disabledBy.comments: El
> Comentario es obligatorio, payments.0.disabledBy.username: Path
> `disabledBy.username` is required., payments.0.disabledBy.uid: Path
> `disabledBy.uid` is required.

Even though the information I want to set in disabledBy is correct, I always get the Mongoose error. How can I set that information? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very strange but it only works if I remove the property from being required. Example of object without required working fine:

```
disabledBy:{
        uid:{
            type: String
        },
        username:{
            type: String
        },
        date:{
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        },
        comments: {
            type: String,
            maxlength:300
        }
    }
```

[image]